# Python gnupg not able to verify a detached-signed file

Tags: python-3.x, gnupg

I have detach signed a file using command line and the following command:

`gpg --output doc.sig --detach-sig "import json.py"`

When I use the following python script to verify the same file using the `doc.sig` it always returns `unverified` and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Python Script:

```
import gnupg 
import tempfile



gpg = gnupg.GPG('/usr/local/bin/gpg')

verified = gpg.verify_file('doc.sig','import json.py')


print ("Verified" if verified else "Unverified")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the answer to the above problem is that you want to make sure you don't have multiple gnupg/gpg installations.

Just one `python-gnupg` install.